# Unrecognized configuration section <configSections> when running clean Umbraco 7.5.8

Tags: .net, visual-studio, umbraco

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac (preview 3). I started a new, empty ASP.NET project and installed Umbraco CMS via NuGet.

The project builds with a warning of:

> Warning: Target 'CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy', not found in the project

It then tries to run but throws an exception:

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section

I've tried running a normal MVC project and it builds and runs fine so I'm guessing that there's something up with Umbraco?

Comment: Umbraco won't (yet) run on OSX, it's based on the older DotNet 4.x while Visual Studio for Mac can only target the newer DotNet Core.  However, work is progressing with support for Umbraco on DotNet Core and iirc should be available around version 8.

Comment: Having said that, some work was done on an older version of Umbraco to port it across to Mono.Net: http://kevinfitzgerald.net/articles/umbraco-and-mono.htm

Comment: Version 8 will not run on .NET Core either. It is "just" a major refactor preparing the project for migrating to Core, which will most likely be v. 9. But apart from that it's correct. The errors are related to unsupported framework version.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comment above.

Umbraco 7 is based on .NET 4.0 but Visual Studio for Mac only supports the newer .NET Core.